# Only Show Nodes From Child Terms (-1 excluding parent)

Tags: 6, views

Hello i have some nodes which i am using as to hold information on a taxonomy term (image, desc etc) and I have created some block views to pull that information to display on my taxonomy/term pages (yes om on D6 due to custom modules and upgrade problems)

Also ive made the term nodes appear on the parents term page in a node view.

- Sport
- -American Sports
- --Baseball
- --NFL
- -Football
- --England
  (etc)

This is in a View with tax depth of -1 (just show the immediate children) If i visit 'Sport' I only see my 'Sport' stuff and then below in the child term (node) View i see

- American Sports
- Football

Well in an ideal world thats all i see but because i am in 'Sport' I also see the node for the 'Sport' term that i am in.

- Sport
- American Sports
- Football

I want the -1 in depth but i dont want the '0' if that makes sense.

I have tried excluding the argument, like you do for for nodes with nid but it doesnt seem to work the same.

Its the same all the way down. If i go into 'American Sports' in my list of nodes that are referance (like that old drupal video from Bob (the christian) 'taxonomy on steroids) shows as-

- American Sports
- Baseball
- NFL

etc.

Aye so in a round about way i was wondering how to exclude...no how to only display, nodes of child terms (-1)

All help appreciated as its been annoying me for a while and ive been trying to sort it for ages.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could add an Node Nid as argument and check "Exclude the argument"

Select "Provide default argument" and select "Taxonomy Term ID from URL"

And then check "Load default argument from term page"

Thank should work for you.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Nah it doesnt seem to like that either Shameem but thaks for the suggestion. I tried that earlier, and again there. The node for 'science' still appears on the 'science tax page' along with child term nodes ('nanotechnology', 'physics' etc). I have my site turned off to the public today till i finish it so i cant even let folks see what i mean. here's a screenshot if it helps anyone http://s9.postimage.org/k8buzxvnj/olbprob.jpg

Comment: Are you passing the term ID or Term name to the page? Or have you aliased the path to taxonomy term page? And why the use of -1 instead of depth 1 if you are looking to show the child nodes. If possible could you send me a screen shot of the views configuration page you are using

Comment: Thaks Shameem. Here is a picture of my view (Views 3) http://s2.postimage.org/x60ev7lsp/blockview.jpg The node argument i added since we spoke and ive had it before and after the tax argument. The view is here - http://pastebin.com/ADTxw73s All works as hoped just i dont want to show level 0 items. Ive tried various filters on the views but the problem is i want 'football' to still appear under 'sport' and its all using the same view. If i could only show nodes of child terms of the term being viewed then that would solve everything i think.

Comment: could you take a screen shot of both the configurations for node id argument and the taxonomy id argument. (Kind of lazy to go through the views export code :-) )

Comment: No your alright Shameem i appreciate your knowledge so anything i can do :) Here is my tax argument (which brings in the 'tag' nodes for 0 and +1 terms) http://s9.postimage.org/ra1zgrzb3/tax_arg.gif and my new nid argument http://s13.postimage.org/637m687o7/nid.gif thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sn7Day0W for an export of the view that works for me.

Comment: Hope you are placing it in the taxonomy term page itself and not in view page. (You are placing the block in the term page and not in a custom view page.)

Comment: Yes the block view i am creating is being attached to a taxonomy/term page Shameem as a block via Context. Your exported view gives me a Unable to interpret view code. in D6 Views 3 Shameem.

Comment: Could you let me know the context configuration you are using.

Comment: The Context can be viewed here Shameem http://pastebin.com/VLNaFQsR i do think the problem is more to do with my block view though than the context. I will go and add an attachment view to my taxonomy/term/* view and remove the context. I think the problem is creating a node view of nodes tagged with terms that are the children of the viewed term whilst excluding nodes of the term being viewed.

Comment: ah hah ive solved it Shameem. I added Taxonomy: Parent term Relationship and then made the argument (Parent) Taxonomy: Term ID and now i just get nodes from the child terms of the node being viewed.

Comment: What I have done is the following just to see that we are on the same page. Created the taxonomy structure as mentioned in your post. Created 1 page per taxonomy term with the same name and term associated with it. ie Sports would have a page named sports and tagged sports. etc and then created the view as mentioned in my answer and then added the block to taxonomy/term page. It lists the nodes as per your requirement that is if I go to the sports taxonomy page I am able to see American Sports and Football. and if I go to American Sports and able to see Baseball and NFS.

Comment: Are you passing the argument through context? If yes then that could be the problem. The block should get the argument from the url.

Comment: is that working with the child nodes. It did not work for me for the child nodes. For the parent node it did work. (I mean the root node)

Comment: Yes it all seems to be working fine Shameem thanks. If i go to American Football it will only show baseball, NFL etc. I had an old term view lying around which just showed child terms. I just took both parent arguements from that and it worked a treat. Thanks for your time and trouble though.

Comment: Welcome and good to know it worked for you Reg Gordon